# How can i get the size of a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, series

I have a pandas series test set y_test. I want to get its size for statistics.

Using this code :

```
print(y_test.shape)
```

I get

```
(31054,)
```

I want to get 31054

Comment: `len(y_test)` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either

`size = y_test.shape[0]`

Which will give first element of the tuple, which is size.
Or you could get it directly using `size` attribute or the `len()` method.

```
size = y_test.size
#or
size = len(y_test)
```

Answer (score 3):

`y_test.shape` gives you a tuple.
So you can do `print(y_test.shape)[0]` to get the first element in the there which is the size of the Series.

`shape` gives you a tuple because it comes from dataframes which give you the shape of the frame in (rows, columns).

Answer (score 1):

Use `len` or [`Series.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.size.html):

```
y_test = pd.Series(range(20))

print(len(y_test))
20

print(y_test.size)
20
```